# Set default colour for all iTerm2 windows

Tags: macos, iterm

How can I set the default terminal colour for all new iTerm2 windows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In its preferences.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

As of build 2.1.4, the method seems to be:

1. In the Colors tab, set the desired colors
2. In the General tab, select the "Default" profile, then click the "Copy Preferences to Profile" button.

[image]

Comment: In version 3.1.5 to get the pictured window to show up, go iterm menu > preferences, and then click the "profile" tab, and then you will see the additional tab options shown above.

Answer (score 3):

In iTerm 3.2.8, this is located under Setting.

[image]